# Approximation on Inverse Mills ratio for the normal R.V

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, approximation

I've come across several approximations for Mills ratio, but I haven't found any good ones for the Inverse Mills ratio. Is there any known closed-form approximation for the Inverse Mills ratio ([link](https://rpubs.com/FJRubio/IMR#:%7E:text=The%20Inverse%20Mills%20Ratio%20(IMR,x)%2Cx%E2%88%88R.)) specifically for a normal random variable, denoted as $\frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)}$ for "$x>0$"? (ratio of normal pdf to normal cdf)

Comment: Why do you want an approximation to something that is already exact and as simple as you might ever hope for, namely the ratio of the pdf to the cdf for the most well-known distribution on the planet (each component of which is already built into every software package)? How does an approximation help you?

Comment: HI @wolfies, to add more on my further need of this approximation is following: I am solving equation which looks like this $\frac{\phi(f(x))}{\Phi(f(x))} = \frac{\phi(g(x))}{\Phi(g(x))}$  where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both linear function. and I need a close form solution of $x$. So I believe some approximation will help me to get it.